# How to restrict a user to log in using only selected clients?

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a resource server and a few clients implementing Oauth2 security.

The flow I'm using is (I don't know the correct name):

```
1) The resource owner try to access a web application (client and resource server).
2) This web application can't even show the index page so the resource owner is redirected 
     to the OAuth2 (Authorization) server passing a client_id and a password in a Basic Auth POST.
3) The Authorization server show a login page and the user enter the username and password.
4) The Authorization server send the user back to the web application and he can
     access the resources (web pages).
```

I have a database with some tables.

[image]

All is working very very fine. What I need? There is no logical relationship between `oauth_client_details` (the applications table) and `users` so any registered user can access any registered client.

I need to restrict a user to access only the applications I choose.

Bonus: Can someone tell me the correct OAuth flow name I'm using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately your description of the flow doesn't fully match with any flows defined by OAuth 2 specification.

HTTP POST for authorization request is valid by the OAuth 2.0 protocol. But I haven't seen sending client credentials in an authorization request.

Closest I can guess this to be [Client Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4) but again step 3 is not there in this flow. So I think you are using a flow that is defined by your organisation.

Now when it comes to client application associations to end users, I think you need another table which store client applications and user identifiers mapping. Your OAuth server must only issue tokens if requesting client application is enabled to an specific end user identity. I'm not a database expert but tables would look like below

```
**Oauth_cliet_details_tab**
---------------------------------------------------
| Client_ID | Client_Secret | Redirect_URL | etc..|
---------------------------------------------------


**Users_tab**
--------------------------------------------------------
|User_ID | User_Name | Email | Hashed_Salted_PWD| etc...
--------------------------------------------------------
```

And now your client application permission tab should look like

```
 **User_client_permisison_tab**
 ----------------------
 |User_ID | Client_ID |
 ----------------------
```

Note that `UserID` is a foreign key from `Users_tab` and `Client_ID` is a foreign key from `Oauth_cliet_details_tab`. Both `User_ID` and `Client_ID` create a composite primary key.

So when your OAuth server get a request, you must validate client credentials, end user credentials and then using client id and end user id, you must check this table for existing record to allow tokens to be issued. You have to somehow add and remove entries from this table and that could be a configuration step.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I almost lost my hopes. I think I made a mistake. I mean "Authorization server" not "Resource server". I took this from an example somewhere. Maybe the original coder want to secure the client access too.. Anyway, if we put the client "login" aside can you guess something? I know how to link the tables but how to tell to Spring to only accept a valid user if he is linked to the asking client? the authentication of each is made in different places in Spring.

Comment: @MagnoC Well, I guessed the same and assumed you were talking about authorization server. One could assume this flow to be implicit flow (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.2) But then again it does not have client authentication step as you mention. So I still believe it's a custom implementation. But as you said, if you forget the client authentication, then it can be considered as implicit flow (please read the spec to get an idea)

Comment: By different places I believe it's different servlets. If that's the case, you have to use request attributes before you forward your request from on another. Since you are first handling client authentication, you must extract client ID there and forward to next servlet through the request. So when you perform end user authentication, you must first validate credentials and then combine client id and user id against your table.

Comment: Good idea. I will try it soon. I alrady take the client id in other part of code to show the user what application is asking for his credentials. Since the user can’t “see” the client login process, I think this could be a good idea. It seems a little the “Login with google “ process. The difference is the client don’t login in google like you said but we must insert the client details including the redirect url in our account. Very closer to what I’m doing.

Comment: You are very clever. I hope I can count on you in future Spring related questions. Since I’m doing some “out of curve” things my questions are not receiving much attention and I’m running out reputation points to reward :-(

Comment: @MagnoC Pleasure to help you with this problem. Yes I will have a look on them :)